# React Native with expo Error : useEffect read-only

Tags: react-native, expo, hook

I tried two steps and i got same error (`useEffect read-only`):

```
const  requestPermission = async ()=> {
    const {granted}= await ImagePicker.requestCameraRollPermissionsAsync;
    if(!granted) 
     alert('You have to enable permission to access photos');
  };

useEffect =(()=> {
 requestPermission();
},[])
```

**and the second way is**

```
useEffect =(()=> {
 const request = async ()=>{
  const {granted}= await ImagePicker.requestCameraRollPermissionsAsync;
  if(!granted)
  alert('You have to enable permission to access photos');
 };
},[])
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an `=` sign in your `useEffect` calls (right after `useEffect`) that is making it look like you're assigning something to `useEffect`

Edited:

```
useEffect(() => {
  requestPermission();
}, [])
```

You would have to edit your other call in the same way.

Comment: Thank you very much that's was a silly mistake :)