# useEffect not firing at all

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My useEffect is not firing at all:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

function Home(props) {    

    useEffect = (() => {
        onPageLoad()
    }, [])

    const onPageLoad = () => {
        console.log('hello from page load')
    }    

    return (        
        <p>Home Component</p>       
    )
}

export default Home
```

I'm stumped on this. There's nothing in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *should* be something some error at least in the developer console in the browser, since it seems you have written a syntax error. You are currently trying to assign a new value to the `import`ed variable `useEffect` but I believe you may have meant to call the function instead:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

function Home(props) {    

    useEffect(() => {
        onPageLoad()
    }, [])

    const onPageLoad = () => {
        console.log('hello from page load')
    }    

    return (        
        <p>Home Component</p>       
    )
}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

Just noticed this, your `useEffect` function is **read-only**. Notice the `=` sign after `useEffect`. Hence, the function might not be getting called.

```
useEffect = (() => {
    onPageLoad()
}, [])
```

Instead, can you please try something like mentioned below.
Also, I suggest try declaring the `onPageLoad` function outside of the `component`.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

const onPageLoad = () => {
  console.log("hello from page load");
};

const Home = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    onPageLoad();
  }, []);

  return <p>Home Component</p>;
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: This totally slipped me!

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error (`Error: "useEffect" is read-only`) in your code. Please have a look at more details about the [Error: useEffect read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66033888/react-native-with-expo-error-useeffect-read-only).

It should be like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    onPageLoad();
  }, []);
```

Instead of this:

```
    useEffect = (() => {
        onPageLoad()
    }, [])
```

Please have a look at the working [CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-rain-pl41rh?file=/src/App.js:66-113).

Answer (score 1):

if you want fire `onPageLoad` for each navigate use `loc=useLocation()` and `loc.path` as dependencies  useEffect   .

```
const onPageLoad=()=>{
alert('hello'); // use alert for better trace
}
const loc=useLocation();
React.useEffect(onPageLoad,[loc.pathname])
```

also please declare and then use-it .  one Clouse function is enough